# Add Anonymous Pages in Web.config ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-config, location

I Declare Web Page Anonymous via entering this Code,

```
<location path="Routing.aspx" >
```

The Above Code is Working Fine,

Now i have Multiple Pages of Routing.aspx, and some prefix is appended with name.

So i am wondering if there is any way i can declare all Pages Anonymous.

Like

```
<location path="***Routing.aspx">
```

Sorry for my Bad English.

Thanks

Shahram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `*routing.aspx` pages into a sub directory.

Then change the path part to something like `<location path="/myroutingfiles/">`

The path part can be a file or **folder** name.